# Find the line number of particular record using JCL

Tags: mainframe, jcl

I have a **input PS file** like
aaa1111zzzz
bbb2222bbbb
ccc3333bbbb
ddd3333cccc
eee7777yyyy

I want to know the line number in this input PS file where the word '3333' is present.. **output should be something like**
3
4
in this scenario

I am looking for a JCL that can do this, I have searched in net, but no luck.

Comment: I believe ISRSUPC can do this, as can a combination of Unix System Services tools.  What have you tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With respect to NicC's answer, I've tried using SORT to attain the expected result.

```
//SORT     EXEC PGM=SYNCSORT                                   
//SORTIN   DD *                                                
aaa1111zzzz                                                    
bbb2222bbbb                                                    
ccc3333bbbb                                                    
ddd3333cccc                                                    
eee7777yyyy                                                    
//SORTOUT  DD SYSOUT=*                                         
//SYSOUT   DD SYSOUT=*                                         
//SYSUDUMP DD SYSOUT=*                                         
//SYSIN DD *                                                   
  INREC FIELDS=(1:SEQNUM,3,ZD,4:1,11)                          
  SORT FIELDS=COPY                                             
  OUTFIL FNAMES=SORTOUT,INCLUDE=(7,4,ZD,EQ,3333),OUTREC=(1:1,3)
/*
```

Comment: You can do it in one step - as I said, you assign the sequence number in the input phase and extract the required sequence number in the output phase INREC, COPY, OUTREC

Comment: @NicC I've edited my answer to meet the result in one step. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

You seem to mis-understand what JCL is.
JCL is not executable, it does not look at data, it does not manipulate data.
JCL is like a memo from you to the operating system requesting the OS to run some programs.
When the JCL is read the OS reads it and sets up whatever it requires to do the tasks defined in the JCL and then DISCARDS the JCL i.e. writes it to the output spool.
The OS then runs the program(s) in accordance with the information it has extracted.

Now, for your task, cschneid has pointed you to one solution. You will have to manipulate the report from superc to get it as you posted.
Or, you can use your sort product as follows:
When reading the records in you ask sort to assign a sequence number to each record. When writing the records out you ask sort to only refer to the records with the value you are looking for and only write out the sequence number for those records.

Comment: I applaud your attempt at education with respect to JCL.  My own efforts [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11405227/cobol-program-jcl-job-or-both/11415004#11415004) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11076078/jcl-get-count-of-non-space-chars-in-a-given-area-mainframe/11076336#11076336) seem to have had little effect.

Comment: I was tempted to edit out the JCL tag, but this answer made me rethink it, as it would allow others who don't understand what JCL is an opportunity to learn. Excellent job, @NicC!

Answer (score 1):

It's a different approach than most people take, but don't forget you can actually use z/OS UNIX Services utilities for tasks like this. In your example, "grep -nr pattern file" would find all the lines matching "pattern" and show you the line numbers.

Of course, the trick is getting the "file" part right when your data is in a conventional dataset...sometimes, easiest is something like this:

```
cat "//'my.dataset.name'" | grep -nr pattern
```

To run this in JCL, you'd put the above command as input into BPXBATCH using JCL like this:

```
//jobname  JOB  ...
//         EXEC PGM=BPXBATCH
//STDERR   DD   PATH='/tmp/mystd.err',
//              PATHOPTS=(OWRONLY,OCREAT,OTRUNC),PATHMODE=SIRWXU
//STDOUT   DD   PATH='/tmp/mystd.out',
//              PATHOPTS=(OWRONLY,OCREAT,OTRUNC),PATHMODE=SIRWXU
//STDPARM  DD   *
    SH cat "//'my.dataset.name'" | grep -nr pattern
```

If you want the STDOUT/STDERR somewhere else (say, SYSOUT), just change the STDERR/STDOUT DD statements.

Using UNIX Services this way is a very cool thing if you're already familiar with UNIX/Linux shell commands...read the details here: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSLTBW_2.1.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r1.bpxa400/toc.htm